# How to stop variables from being updated?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

After training a neural network in Tensorflow, how do you stop it from updating weights and biases to test their current values? From what I know, you can inspect them with `inspect_checkpoint.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file`, but what it gives you as an output is nothing to calculate with. I already tried:

- `tf.train.Saver.restore` - this only brings backpropagation back to life after the variables had been saved (the complete opposite of what I want to acchieve!)
- `tf.variable_scope.reuse_variables` - doesn't work eighter
- `tf.stop_gradient` - astonishingly lets a set of values appear twice in a loop `in range (0,10)` where the variables are printed. In all other iterations, however, the variables adopt other values.

Comment: How to you want to test values? While running, you can use tf.Print to view values in every iteration. If you want to do computations, you can define an tf operation and sess.run that operation. If you want to run gradient descent and update gradients for specific list of variables, you can specify which variables to update by supplying variable list to opt.minimize(...,var_list=list_of_variables_for_which_to_update_gradients).

Comment: I keep having problems with testing values while running the training session. As my declarations are chained to what regulates the dataflow (`iterator.get_next()`), printing `sess.run` for any tensor shifts the inputs and labels apart from another. The only way to test the network I currently see is to close the training session without outputting anything and reuse the trained weights and biases to do some calculation on new data.

Comment: If you don't want a tensor `t` to be updated by an operation `op` but want to get its value stop calling `sess.run(op)` and just call `sess.run(t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update operation (e.g. the call to `optimize`) is done only if you run the corresponding operation. If you want to have access to the value of a variable without updating it, don't run the update operation (for example the `train_op` or a `tf.assign`), and only evaluate the variable:

```
import tensorflow as tf
weight = tf.Variable(0.0)
op = tf.assign_add(weight, 1) # update weight by adding 1 to it
with tf.Session() as sess:   
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     print(sess.run(weight)) # Get the value of the weight
     print(sess.run(op))     # Update the weight
     print(sess.run(weight)) # Get the value of the weight but don't update it
     print(sess.run(weight)) # Get the value of the weight
```

will print:

```
0.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

Comment: With your explanation the mechanism seems so much trivial! I now have a loop in which I train the network with incoming inputs, after which I just declare new inputs and `sess.run` the outputs. Running weights and biases in the same manner doesn't make them change - hooray!